# Momentum-independent quantum field quantization

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation

How would we quantize a field which is not Fourier-transformable into energy-momentum space? The equation can be separated into a time dependent and position dependent function, but the space solution cannot be expressed as a fourier transform. What does this mean? Is this saying that we don't have momentum?

The equation to solve is in these notes: https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02764, top of page 18. A solution to a 1+1 metric is given, but it also doesn't have a energy eigenvalue, which I cannot make sense out of.

What I have tried to do is to impose the equal time commutation relation. But since my solution is r-dependent, it doesn't give me a delta function, but a function in terms of r.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can certainly Fourier transform the field. But that might not be useful as the background space-time is not translation invariant. In cases like these, people try to get as far as they can with mode expansions where $e^{ipx}$ is replaced by some formal symbol understood to be a solution of the wave equation.

Comment: @ConnorBehan - what do you mean by a solution to the wave equation? Do you mean the solution to my equationg in the background spacetime? Also, I don't understand what you mean by some formal symbol. Would you mind clarifying this for me?

Comment: $f_n(x) \leftarrow$ that's a formal symbol for the $n$-th eigenfunction of the curved space Laplacian. Sure, that may be an empty statement. But famous papers like https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-43/issue-3/Particle-creation-by-black-holes/cmp/1103899181.full have done a lot by using abstract properties of solutions that were too complicated to express in closed form.